# How to apply validation?

Tags: php, yii

Hi have a table in which i have many fields but i need to put validation in fields.

1)user_mobile
    2)admin_mobile
    3)user_email
    4)admin_email

all these are saved in same database i want to apply unique validation on email and mobile. Such that no user and admin has same mobile or email. I used following rule but it don't solve my problem. Please help. Any help is appreciated.

```
public function rules()
{
array('user_mobile,admin_mobile,user_email,admin_email','unique',
'message'=>'{attribute} already exist')

}
```

It works only for user's and admin. but i want no new user or admin has same mobile no and not same email. 
but this validation not matching admin_email with user_email and admin_mobile with user_mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add one condition for check if you have add validation in controller.

```
public function actionname(){
       $model = new modelname; // model name enter here 
       $model->setattributes($_post['modelname']) // set record into model 
  if($model->validate()){
       $this->redirect('index);
     }else{ ... }
```

Comment: Please add your code to the answer that it'll be more clear

Comment: public function actionname(){

$model = new modelname; // model name enter here
$model->setattributes($_post['modelname']) // set record into model
if($model->validate()){
    $this->redirect('index);
}else{
Print_r($model->getErrors());
}
}

Answer (score 1):

```
   public function actionname(){

   $model = new modelname; // model name enter here 

   $model->setattributes($_post['modelname']) // set record into model
```